# Cocoa - Get all information of Address Book

Tags: ios, cocoa, contacts

Is there any simple way to get all the information of all contacts on my address book, in a dictionary?

Comment: Simple? Not happening. Address book is where simplicity goes to die. Also, *address

Answer (score 3):

Simple? I don't know about that, but there is a way. Check out the Apple Documentation, here is a [pdf document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone.pdf) to help conceptualize this.

Comment: What I mean by simple, is like instead of access the Person field by field, I just want an dictionary with all info at once :). but tks for the help!